# wpf listbox with < 10k entries... how do i make it effiecient?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

iphone has 10 listbox entries at a time, it doesnt' load all 10k entries and scroll them all at the same time.  it adds one entry, and subtracts one entry at a time.  so how do you do this in a wpf listbox?  how do i make, say 20 listbox entries, and add one or two, and subtract the same amount?  does data binding the listbox take care of this performance issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListBox WPF control uses a VirtualizingStackPanel by default, unless you change the ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll property false, in which case you get smooth scrolling in exchange for a loss of virtualization.

Comment: so is this something i shouldn't worry about because it is handled for me?

Comment: @darthwillard - you will need to look at turning on Recycling in order to make sure you use your memory as efficiently as possible though.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the `VirtualizingStackPanel`.  This control will only display the items you actually need on screen, even if you have thousands more that are available to the item.  Here is the MSDN article about it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx

Here is a small article about this control that explains it simply:

http://windowsclient.net/blogs/microsoft_kc/archive/2009/05/13/what-is-virtualizing-stackpanel.aspx

One key point in this second article is that you should use the `Recycling` property to make sure you use the least amount of resources like so:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```